# Can't portforward properly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, port

Can't port forward properly even though I have configured everything correctly. I want to port forward for a Minecraft server in the port 25565 but "https://canyouseeme.org/" cannot see me I don't know why.[Image of Open ports checked using zenmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRw1S.jpg)
[Image of Portforwarded the same ports here also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbWLu.png)

Comment: Your ISP may be using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: How do I know that if they are using Carrier-Grade NAT? btw I have a new optical connection which was upgraded in the near past before that I had a normal modem in that one I had successfully port forwarded.

Comment: Look at your public IP address.

Comment: My ISP is not using Carrier-Grade NAT, My wan IP address are not the same from whatsmyip and router login page

Comment: @DSJONFIRE - There are numerous websites that will display the IP address it detects.  If you are behind a CG NAT then the IP address will not be a public ip address (i.e. 192.168.0.X) instead of a public ip address

Comment: Ya,they are  not like this for me

Comment: "My wan IP address are **not the same** from whatsmyip and router login page" - that usually means Carrier Grade NAT.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for resolving my doughts on the subject :)